# Android bundle is null after replacing fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-studio, android-volley, android-bundle

I have two fragments which are VolleyFragment and AnotherFragment, setting VolleyFragment as the initial fragment. In this fragment, the bundle data is displaying ok. However, when I go to AnotherFragment, the app crashes. It says this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] android.os.Bundle.getStringArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.example.rendell.volleyfragment.AnotherFragment.onCreateView(AnotherFragment.java:28)
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String JSON_URL = "http://192.168.0.102/musicmania/music/getMF";

TextView id,name,email;
String[] ids, names, emails;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.id);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);

    sendRequest();


}

private void sendRequest(){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(json);
    pj.parseJSON();

    id.setText(ParseJSON.ids[0]);
    name.setText(ParseJSON.titles[0]);
    email.setText(ParseJSON.artists[0]);

    FragmentManager fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentTransaction.beginTransaction();
    VolleyFragment squadFragment = new VolleyFragment();
    AnotherFragment anotherFragment = new AnotherFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putStringArray("id", ParseJSON.ids);
    bundle.putStringArray("name", ParseJSON.titles);
    bundle.putStringArray("email", ParseJSON.artists);
    squadFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    anotherFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    transaction.replace(R.id.containerView, squadFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}

public void changeFragment(View view) {
    FragmentManager fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager();
    android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentTransaction.beginTransaction();
    AnotherFragment anotherFragment = new AnotherFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.containerView, anotherFragment);
    transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

VolleyFragment

```
public class VolleyFragment extends Fragment {

TextView id,name,email;

String[] ids,names,emails;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.volley_fragment, container, false);
    id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
    name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email);

    ids = getArguments().getStringArray("id");
    names = getArguments().getStringArray("name");
    emails = getArguments().getStringArray("email");

    //jsonArray.setIds(id);
    id.setText(/*jsonArray.getIds()*/ids[0]);
    name.setText(names[0]);
    email.setText(emails[0]);
    return view;
    }

}
```

AnotherFragment

```
public class AnotherFragment extends Fragment {

TextView id,name,email;

String[] ids,names,emails;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.another_fragment, container, false);
    id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
    name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email);

    ids = getArguments().getStringArray("id");
    names = getArguments().getStringArray("name");
    emails = getArguments().getStringArray("email");

    //jsonArray.setIds(id);
    id.setText(/*jsonArray.getIds()*/ids[0]);
    name.setText(names[0]);
    email.setText(emails[0]);
    return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble following exactly what you're doing here, but I see a number of problems:

- In showJSON, you new up a ParseJSON object and assign it to pj, but never make use of pj. Instead you reach statically into ParseJSON for the values to populate a Bundle.  That seems really odd. I'd expect the pj instance to contain the data.
- Typically one does not "new" up a fragment. The usual pattern is to use a static builder in the class of the fragment itself.
- You're passing the same Bundle to two different fragments. Unless you know for a fact that's OK, try instead using a different Bundle for each one.
- in showJSON, your AnotherFragment instance doesn't seem to be used at all
- I don't see any place where changeFragment is called
- You're passing string arrays in the Bundle, but you only ever use the first element in the array in the fragment.  Consider just passing a single string instead?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion of my code. I was getting desperate because of my deadline, that's why I tried different methods and left some snippets unused for my code to try to work. Anyway, I just solve this and will be sharing my solution in a moment.